# Parse CloudCode and nested/looped queries

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I have been trying to wrap my head around Promises in Parse Cloud Code but am struggling. Here is what I am trying to do:

- Run a query to get a list of items

  - Foreach item, change a value, and save
  - After saving, send a push message

Each time I try this, the saves complete, but the async pushes do not. I understand I need to use Promises, but I don't see many solid examples for how to do this inside loops, AND in a chain (the push after the save). Can someone help out?

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're actually asking for here.

Comment: Can you post the code you have as it will make it easier to answer. I have a similar piece of code working.